# Extending Managed Microsoft AD to on-premises Servers

Tags: active-directory, microsoft

I'm researching the possibility of extending Managed Microsoft AD to a secondary Active Directory creating a basic replication structure between primary AD (GCP) and secondary AD (on-prem). Apparently it is not possible to configure this extension, nor to fully migrate Managed Microsoft AD to an on-prem infrastructure. Does anyone know how to point out some documentation that I can clarify this doubt?

Thanks!